# OpenGL ES 2.0 vector translation not working via matrix multiplication (in vertex shader)

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm building a sprite (rectangle with a texture) class in Java (Android) with OpenGL ES 2.0.

My goal is to only use a section of the texture, therefore I pass a matrix to the vertex shader. In the following example I'd like to only see right half of the texture (but I'm seing the left half), scaled over the full sprite width:

```
/ 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5 \      / x \       / 0.5 * x + 0.5 \
| 0  , 1, 0, 0   |  \/  | y |  ---  |       y       |
| 0  , 0, 1, 0   |  /\  | 1 |  ---  |       1       |
\ 0  , 0, 0, 1   /      \ 1 /       \       1       /
```

If I put in my texture coordinates, it works just fine (on paper):

```
(0,1) -> (0.5,1) // bottom left
(1,1) -> (1,  1) // bottom right
(0,0) -> (0.5,0) // top left
(1,0) -> (1,  0) // top right
```

But in reality I get these results:

```
(0,1) -> (0  ,1)
(1,1) -> (0.5,1)
(0,0) -> (0  ,0)
(1,0) -> (0.5,0)
```

Which means that the scaling part works, but the translation part doesn't.

**Code**:

**Vertex Shader**:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texturePosition;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 textureMatrix;
varying vec2 iTexturePosition;
void main() {
  gl_Position = mvpMatrix * position;

  vec4 tp = vec4(texturePosition.x, texturePosition.y, 1, 1);
  tp = textureMatrix * tp;
  //tp[0] += 0.5;
  iTexturePosition = tp.xy;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D textureUnit;
varying vec2 iTexturePosition;
void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(textureUnit, iTexturePosition);
  if (color.a <= 0.25) {
    discard;
  }
  if (iTexturePosition[0] <= 0.4) {
    //discard;
  }
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

**Java-side**:

```
private static int textureMatrixHandle = -1;
private static final String textureMatrixName = "textureMatrix";
private float[] textureMatrix = new float[16];

// more code ...

@Override
public void draw { // only relevant lines
    textureMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(glProgram, textureMatrixName);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(textureMatrix, 0);
    setTextureSection(textureMatrix, 0, 0.5f, 1, 1, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(textureMatrixHandle, 1, false, textureMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, VERTEX_COUNT);
}

protected void translateTextureSection(float[] textureMatrix, float x, float y) {
    Matrix.multiplyMM(textureMatrix, 0, new float[] {
            1, 0, 0, x,
            0, 1, 0, y,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
    }, 0, textureMatrix, 0);
}

protected void scaleTextureSection(float[] textureMatrix, float x, float y) {
    Matrix.multiplyMM(textureMatrix, 0, new float[] {
            x, 0, 0, 0,
            0, y, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1,
    }, 0, textureMatrix, 0);
}

protected void rotateTextureSection(float[] textureMatrix, float angle) {
    angle = (float) Math.toRadians(angle);
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(angle);
    float cos = (float) Math.cos(angle);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(textureMatrix, 0, new float[] {
            cos, -sin, 0, 0,
            sin,  cos, 0, 0,
              0,    0, 1, 0,
              0,    0, 0, 1,
    }, 0, textureMatrix, 0);
}

protected void setTextureSection(float[] textureMatrix, float rotationAngle, float left, float right, float bottom, float top) {
    rotateTextureSection(textureMatrix, rotationAngle);
    translateTextureSection(textureMatrix, left, top);
    scaleTextureSection(textureMatrix, right - left, bottom - top);
}
```

Comment: Are you passing true or false for the transpose flag when calling glUniformMatrixf4v (or whatever it is)?

Comment: i'm passing false. scaling happens on the x coordinate as expected (i'm seing the full height of the texture and half of the width, it's just the wrong half of the width)

Comment: @samgak I'm setting the uniform like this: GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(textureMatrixHandle, 1, false, textureMatrix, 0);

Comment: Passing true instead doesn't fix the problem? It will depend on how you are setting up the matrix

Comment: no, sadly it didnt fix the problem

Comment: post the code where you initialize the matrix

Comment: @samgak done. I'll add a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) tomorrow. Thanks for the support so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that Java was using with row-major matrices while [OGL ES only supports column-major matrices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15032/why-must-the-transpose-value-of-gluniformmatrix4fv-in-webgl-opengl-es-be-false). Meaning the following matrix

```
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

was interpreted as

```
/ 0.5, 0, 0, 0 \      / x \       / 0.5 * x           \
| 0  , 1, 0, 0 |  \/  | y |  ---  |       y           |
| 0  , 0, 1, 0 |  /\  | 1 |  ---  |       1           |
\ 0.5, 0, 0, 1 /      \ 1 /       \       1 + 0.5 * x /
```

which obviously doesn't transpose the coordinate.

Transposing the matrix before passing it to OGL ES solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you are calling [Matrix.MultiplyMM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#multiplyMM(float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20float[],%20int)). The result is undefined if the same elements of the result array are used as one of the inputs:

> The same float array may be passed for result, lhs, and/or rhs. However, the result element values are undefined if the result elements overlap either the lhs or rhs elements.

So, change your functions to use a temp matrix, e.g:

```
float[] tempMatrix = new float[16];
protected void translateTextureSection(float[] textureMatrix, float x, float y) {        
    Matrix.multiplyMM(tempMatrix, 0, new float[] {
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            x, y, 0, 1,
    }, 0, textureMatrix, 0);
    System.arraycopy( tempMatrix, 0, textureMatrix, 0, tempMatrix.length );
}
```

Also, the matrix needs to be transposed because Open GL uses column major order but the float array you are passing is in row major order. Setting the transpose flag when you call glUniformMatrixf4v is not supported in Open GLES so you need to do it yourself.

Comment: But the matrix looks as expected:

textureMatrix = {float[16]@831879063544} 
 (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

Comment: Try transposing the matrix yourself and passing it in with the transpose flag set to false. The flag isn't supported apparently http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15032/why-must-the-transpose-value-of-gluniformmatrix4fv-in-webgl-opengl-es-be-false